# while creating reactjs app its showing error below

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have installed 'create-react-app'. But while creating reactjs app its showing error below. How can I solve this?

**reactjs**

```
    E:\reactjs\project\helloworld\hello>create-react-app hi
    
    Creating a new React app in E:\reactjs\project\helloworld\hello\hi.
    
    Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
    Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...
    
    events.js:292
          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
    
    Error: spawn C:\Program Files\heroku\bin ENOENT
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
        at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
    Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
        at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\dwipal shrirao\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
        at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
      errno: 'ENOENT',
      code: 'ENOENT',
      syscall: 'spawn C:\\Program Files\\heroku\\bin',
      path: 'C:\\Program Files\\heroku\\bin',
      spawnargs: [
        '/d',
        '/s',
        '/c',
        '"npm ^"install^" ^"--save^" ^"--save-exact^" ^"--loglevel^" ^"error^" ^"react^" ^"react-dom^" ^"react-scripts@0.9.x^""'
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried ***not*** installing it locally and running it via the `npx` command as recommended in the docs? https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app

Comment: [May be that will help](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7251)

Comment: now showing this error:            i>npx create-react-app hello
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npx: command not found: create-react-app

Comment: `npx` is part of npm. What versions of node and nom are you running?

Answer (score 0):

if you're seeing this error you're certainly an outdated version of the CLI